# Subclassing and modifying QStateMachine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstatemachine

Let's say I have a pack of robots that run a  `QStateMachine`. All state machines of those robots have the same basic structure:

- States:

  - Sleep
  - Search
  - Destroy
  - Return
- Transitions (`from` -> `to` on `signal`:

  - Sleep -> Search on "next"
  - Search -> Destroy on "next"
  - Destroy -> Search on "next"
  - Destroy -> Return on "back"
  - Search -> Return on "back"
  - Return -> Search on "next"
  - Return -> Sleep on "back"

// base.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QState>
#include <QStateMachine>

class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Base(QObject* parent = 0);
    ~Base();

signals:
    void next();
    void back();

private:
    QStateMachine m_machine;
    QState* m_sleep;
    QState* m_search;
    QState* m_destroy;
    QState* m_return;
};
```

// base.cpp

```
Base::Base(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_sleep = new QState(&m_machine);
    m_search = new QState(&m_machine);
    m_destroy = new QState(&m_machine);
    m_return = new QState(&m_machine);

    m_machine.setInitialState(m_sleep);

    m_sleep->addTransition(this, &Base::next, m_search);
    m_search->addTransition(this, &Base::next, m_destroy);
    m_search->addTransition(this, &Base::back, m_return);
    m_destroy->addTransition(this, &Base::next, m_search);
    m_destroy->addTransition(this, &Base::back, m_return);
    m_return->addTransition(this, &Base::next, m_search);
    m_return->addTransition(this, &Base::back, m_sleep);

    m_machine.start();
}
```

Now I want to have a robot that is maybe a bit more concrete. Let's say he is more detailed in the process of destruction, featuring a couple of substates, e.g. `dismantel -> sprayWithAcid -> blowUp -> desintegrate`, where he moves on with each `next`-signal, or he goes on to `return` upon the `back`-signal.

As mentioned, my plan was to just add them as substates to the state `destroy`, but as the signal `next` will not only continue the substatemachine until finished, but also leave the parent state.

**How can I avoid this?** or is there another nice way to do similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now.

The trick is to create the transitions explicitly, having them as members of the class. You can set them up like this:

```
m_sleepSearch = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::next, m_sleep);
m_searchDestroy = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::next, m_search);
m_searchReturn = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::back, m_search);
m_destroySearch = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::next, m_destroy);
m_destroyReturn = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::back, m_destroy);
m_returnSearch = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::next, m_return);
m_returnSleep = new QSignalTransition(this, &Base::back, m_return);

m_sleepSearch->setTargetState(m_search);
m_searchDestroy->setTargetState(m_destroy);
m_searchReturn->setTargetState(m_return);
m_destroySearch->setTargetState(m_search);
m_destroyReturn->setTargetState(m_return);
m_returnSearch->setTargetState(m_search);
m_returnSleep->setTargetState(m_sleep);
```

What I first got wrong was having the wrong parameters for the `QSignalTransition(sender, signal, source_state)` constructor as it is too similar to the syntax of `->addTransition(sender, signal, target_state)` so I mixed up `source` and `target`.

After having them created like this, it should be easy to re-route or disable some of those transitions, when subclassing this object.